# copying images to certain folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am new to python I am trying to build a small script that can collect images from all over the server, I have certain image naming:

```
AMZ_1004.jpg
AMZ_1272.jpg
GOO_1.jpeg
GOO_2.png
```

I want the script to look through every directory and copy (not move) the files into AMZ & GOO

```
import shutil,os

goo_dst = '/home/usr2/Pictures/GOO'
amz_dst = '/home/usr2/Pictures/AMZ'
os.makedirs(goo_dst,exist_ok=1)
os.makedirs(amz_dst,exist_ok=1)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
    for name in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, name)
        if name.startswith('GOO_') and (name.endswith('.jpg') or name.endswith('.jpeg') or name.endswith('.png')):
            shutil.copyfile(path, goo_dst)
        elif name.startswith('AMZ_') and name.endswith('.jpg'):
            shutil.copyfile(path, amz_dst)
```

the script runs ok, is there a way speed the process ?

the script runs on Arch Linux if it matters

Comment: Check this out - [Faster recursive directory walk for Python.](https://pypi.org/project/faster-than-walk/)

Comment: @CavinDsouza I run python 2.7 , don't think that will work

Comment: ohh, shoot. It seems that `os.walk()` calls `os.listdir()` recursively which also fetches the meta-information of the files as well which makes it slow. `os.scandir()` is similar and faster but again I think it isn't supported on v2.7

Comment: Is `shutil` the fastest way to copy a file?  Just based on the name it seems like it might shell out to a separate process, which is a lot of overhead.

Comment: You can try multiprocessing

Comment: If multiple files with the same name are found, that last found overwrites prior versions.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest optimization you can make to the script is not starting your search on the filesystem root.

This method goes over many things that are not files (such as the `/dev` and `/proc` folders) as well as over system folder where your files are unlikely to exist.
(You don't really expect any images to be under `/bin` or `/usr/bin` right?)

Try to narrow down the real search path, such as `/var/www` which is where Apache folders reside.

Another optimization might be not using Python at all, but instead shell script directly:

```
#!/bin/sh
GOO_DST='/home/usr2/Pictures/GOO'
AMZ_DST='/home/usr2/Pictures/AMZ'

mkdir -p ${GOO_DST}
mkdir -p ${AMZ_DST}

find / -type f -name 'GOO_*.jpg' -o -name 'GOO_*.jpeg' -o -name 'GOO_*.png' -exec cp {} ${GOO_DST} \;

find / -type f -name 'AMZ_*.jpg' -exec cp {} ${AMZ_DST} \;
```

The `find` utility should give you faster results than manual traversal.

If you insists on using Python, at least move the `path = os.path.join(root, name)` to avoid some extra work on files that are not relevant (which is most files).
This is a tiny optimization, but can still help.

Another option would be using multithreading to parallelize the search, but you will need to manually decide which part of the filesystem each thread will search.

If 2 threads go over the same folders, it will be an even bigger waste of time.
Also, note that multithreading this script might cause it to take more CPU while running.

[Read here for more details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you need python implementation, you can speed up via async call of shutil (that should allow shutil to run in parallel for different files)

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def async_copyfile(src, dst):
    yield shutil.copyfile(src, dst)    

def generate_tasks():
    goo_dst = '/home/usr2/Pictures/GOO'
    amz_dst = '/home/usr2/Pictures/AMZ'
    os.makedirs(goo_dst,exist_ok=1)
    os.makedirs(amz_dst,exist_ok=1)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
        for name in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            if name.startswith('GOO_') and (name.endswith('.jpg') or name.endswith('.jpeg') or name.endswith('.png')):
                yield (path, goo_dst)
            elif name.startswith('AMZ_') and name.endswith('.jpg'):
                yield (path, amz_dst)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(async_copyfile(src, dst)) for src, dst in generate_tasks()]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

Comment: I like this solution, but is asyncio present in python-2.7 which the OP is using?  I thought asyncio was only added in 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) than use python script. The `rsync` which stands for "remote sync", is a remote and local file synchronization tool. It uses an algorithm that minimizes the amount of data copied by only moving the portions of files that have changed. for example in your case;

```
rsync -a "$PWD" --include='*/' --include='GOO_*.jpg' --include='GOO_*.jpeg' --include='GOO_*.png' --exclude='*' /home/usr2/Pictures/GOO/

rsync -a "$PWD" --include='*/' --include='AMZ_*.jpg' --exclude='*' /home/usr2/Pictures/AMZ/
```

Or you can also use the simply way;

```
rsync $(pwd)/GOO_*.{jpg,jpeg,png} /home/usr2/Pictures/GOO/

rsync $(pwd)/AMZ_*.jpg /home/usr2/Pictures/AMZ/
```

Finally, combine it with `mkdir` *(if you need to create the path also)*;

```
#!/bin/bash

GOO_PATH='/home/usr2/Pictures/GOO/'
AMZ_PATH='/home/usr2/Pictures/AMZ/'

mkdir -p ${GOO_PATH} && rsync $(pwd)/GOO_*.{jpg,jpeg,png} ${GOO_PATH}
mkdir -p ${AMZ_PATH} && rsync $(pwd)/AMZ_*.jpg ${AMZ_PATH}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python2.7 on linux, you could use optimizations like:

- using built in system cp
- batching files for the copy
- TODO: batching the calls to `find_files` iterator

I'll let you time them and see if they help.

I wouldn't expect parallelizing the copies to help very much as each copy is in contention for the disk.

```
import shutil, os

goo_dst = '/home/usr2/Pictures/GOO'
amz_dst = '/home/usr2/Pictures/AMZ'


def find_files(path='/'):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            if name.startswith('GOO_') and (name.endswith('.jpg') or name.endswith('.jpeg') or name.endswith('.png')):
                yield(path, goo_dst)
            elif name.startswith('AMZ_') and name.endswith('.jpg'):
                yield(path, amz_dst)

def my_cp(dst, files):
    # we use array form to avoid problems with file paths containing spaces
    return subprocess.call(["cp"] + files, shell=False)

def main:
    os.makedirs(goo_dst, exist_ok=1)
    os.makedirs(amz_dst, exist_ok=1)

    files = {goo_dst: [],
             amz_dst: []}
    base_path = '/' # limit this if possible, www/data perhaps?
    min_copy = 50 # tune for your needs
    for path, dest in find_files(base_path):
        files[dest].append(path)
        if len(files[dest]) > min_copy:
            my_cp(dest, files[dest])
            files[dest] = []
    # clean up any remaining files
    for dest, paths in files.iter_items(): 
        if paths:
            my_cp(paths, dest)
main()
```